# Development environment in Docker

Tags: docker, development-environment

Due to a hardware issue, I had to change my work station to another Mac for a few weeks.
It took me a couple of hours to setup everything: Android Studio, git, Apache, MySql, etc...

Could I use a docker image to bundle all my development tools ?
(My goal is to have a "backup" of my development environment that I could start running right away on another machine)

Answer (score 0):

> Could I use a docker image to bundle all my development tools ?

That means all your dev tools would be *Linux* tools working in Linux container, on a Linux host.

You would need to provide that Linux host (on your Mac) through a [**boot2docker**](http://boot2docker.io/) Virtual Machine.

But that also mean you could not directly type "`git`" from a Mac shell, you would need to connect to your VM first in order to launch your '`git`' container and run dome `docker run --name=git` commands.

So no, this doesn't seem to be a good fit for your backup plan on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. It kinda depends what you are looking for in a development environment.

I do use it for *part* of my dev env though.

### Vagrant + Docker

My personal approach is to rely on Vagrant to fire up a bunch of environments, some of which being full-fledged VMs and others being lightweight containers.

This is a rather controversial approach though, many people would not agree with it, as the tools overlap, both in terms of platform capability and provisioning.

#### Docker Containers for 3rd Party Services

My personal approach for this is to use Vagrant to fire up a bunch of different VMs, where one is my main dev VM with tools I use for development (IDEs, editors, SCM tools, etc...), and the rest are Docker containers for 3rd party apps that relate to my daily activities (IRC client, database servers like MySQL or MongoDB, etc...).

This fits my cycle decently as these types of tools (like databases) are not something you generally interact with directly through a tty, but something I'd rather connect to with another tool via an API. So I don't need direct access to them, and I do want them to be isolated and easy to jumpstart and dispose of when I jump between projects.

So, docker containers fit *part* of my idea of a dev environment, but not necessarily all of it.

Just my use case though. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Shameless plug: Docker Shell

This tool lets you set up a uniform cross platform development environment inside a docker container.

http://dockershell.io/